# merge two tables with No variables in common

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I have two tables of different row size (which may vary). The variable name is different (no variable name in common). When I try to join these I get an error that no keys are common. Is there a command that would join these two tables? Or how can do this best?

t1=
Var1
a
b
c

t2=
Var2
1
2

I would like to end up with:

t3=
var1 Var2
a 1
b 1
c 1
a 2
b 2
c 2

I tried join, innerjoin and outerjoin but did not get it to work. I am probably missing something... preferably I would like to join an arbitrary number of tables.

Comment: `repmat` might work for you. I'd rather use something like `meshgrid` but that doesnt work with char-variables if Im not mistaken.

Comment: it is important that it works with text and digits. I would have to write a custom function with repmat() in it to "expand" the tables?

Answer (score 1):

Use a dummy variable `Var3 = 1` for every row in both tables. Now you have a common column. `OUTERJOIN` works and at the end delete `Var3`.